ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR cloudflare when turn on proxy
I have a VPS installed webmin as control panel.
I directed all domains via cloudflare. For the past few days I'm getting below error.
This site can’t be reached
The web page at https://domain-name might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

interestingly, I can access the websites if I use VPN.
after hours of investigation, I found that if I turn proxy of at cloudflare, domains are accessible, but no SSL.
is turning off proxy only solution? or am I missing something?

It depends on your objective. Do you want CF to resolve the DNS address on your website? Or do you want CF to proxy all the requests to you website and might be caching some data or fo preprocessing or something else?

The error string looks interesting as well - "ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR" Does your website support QUIC / HTTP3? If not, I assume it might be the misconfiguration, one of two:
CF try to reach you website using QUIC and site do not support it.
The client tries to reach CF with QUIC, and it fails. Usually sites implementing fallbacks to HTTP2 in case of QUIC(HTTP3).

You can evaluate you client(WEB browser) QUIC support using this page https://datascrape.tech/tools/browser-leaks-test/ . 2nd table row will show you the public IP address or error message.
If you are using proxies or some VPC clients like Outline, they might not support UDP. If so, it will cause problems for any UDP traffic including QUIC.

I disabled the proxy, used only dns for all domains and subdomains.
i setup ssl directly from the server. I'm using webmin control panel, so option is manage virtual server > setup SSL certificate > SSL providers > request certificate.
i believe cpanel, directadmin alike control panels has manual option to setup ssl.
